# WordPress 301 redirect for all pages

Tags: wordpress, apache

I have a WordPress site for which I wish to force all pages to go to https and non-www

So I want following redirection.

http://example.com --> https://example.com 
www.example.com --> https://example.com 
http://example.com/abcd --> https://example.com/abcd 
www.example.com/abcd --> https://example.com/abcd

I have following code in my .htaccess file

```
    # BEGIN WordPress
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=301]

    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
    </IfModule>
    # END WordPress
```

The problem is that it only redirects the home page correctly, for inner pages I get a Page not Found/Site cannot be reached error.

Comment: A simple google gave this: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-redirect-http-to-https-using-htaccess/

Comment: I have googled this issue and visited numerous pages. I would not have posted a question here if I had found an answer in google search or in a previously asked question.

The article for which you have provided a link does not specify how to redirect all www traffic to non-www, please read the question carefully.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)(.+) [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?(.+)
RewriteRule ^ https://%2%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thanks, this is good. Tried this, it's still not working for the inner pages. And its not working for http to https. It only works for https://www to https://non-www.